# Is there a jqm tumbler ui element?

Tags: user-interface, jqmobi

I'm building an app in JQM which receives user input using standard form elements.

One of the user inputs is a time of day and I was hoping to use a nice 'tumbler' ui element [Like this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-components-symbian/qml-tumbler.html).

Can't find anything in the documentation to cover this. Does anyone know if this is possible? If there is a plugin etc.

Thanks

Comment: Is this "jqmobi" or "jQuery Mobile" ??

Comment: Here is a beta plugin for jqMobi https://github.com/imaffett/jq.spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery Mobile, you can use [this plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/).  I have used it on several occasions and it works great.  It sounds like you want the [Time Flip Mode](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/mode/timeflipbox.html)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a plugin to do this, but would be great to see someone create this.

Matteo Spinelli has a standalone plugin that does this - http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch